# How Can I Use ngFor and ngModel on a map in Angular

Tags: angular, dictionary, ngfor, ngmodel

I have a Map app_access; which represents a list of applications and Boolean values of access to those applications. I want to use ngFor and ngModel to control the Boolean values in the map.

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
<div *ngFor="let app of app_access">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="app.value" />
<div/>
```

I can't get this to work on my app and get an error about Maps not being iterable.

Comment: use the `keyvalue` pipe. `<div *ngFor="let app of app_access | keyvalue">`

Comment: You should formulate an answer as this is actually one :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly I am using angular 5 (stupid, but I can't use the newest version for reasons) and don't have access to keyvalue pipe. Do you know another work around?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You will need to first correct the typo with the closing tag of your div.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwbtbz)

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  app_access = [{
    value: true,
    name: 'Cx1'
  }];
}
```

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let app of app_access">
    {{app.name}} <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="app.value" />
</div>

{{ app_access[0].value}}
```